# How to divide columns with zeros and nulls

Tags: sql, oracle11g

just a simple question but somehow I can't find an answer here.

I have two columns (A and B). Both contains numbers with zeros and null. I would like to get a division one by the other to get information about the ratio between each single row but I am getting ORA-01476.
I know the divisior is equal to zero but I would like to get in this row a number and not an error for whole query

```
A    B
1    5
2    Null
3    0
NULL 3
0    4
4
```

I am using sql developer.

Comment: You could just eliminate null's and zero's using a where clause.  if you must have the rows; what do you want to happen when 0, Null are in the denominator? 1?

Comment: `NULL` in any position of a math operation will give you another `NULL`. It has no value. How do those numbers relate to each other and what are you trying to calculate by dividing? Also, I'm fairly certain that if you try to divide by 0 too many times, you'll tear a hole in the space-time continuum and we'll all simply disappear. Or so I heard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you divide a number by zero you get an error, because the answer to such division is undefined. SQL, however, has a value for undefined: `NULL`. So make the result `NULL`instead:

```
select a, b, case when b = 0 then null else a / b end as ratio
from mytable;
```

or

```
select a, b, a / case when b = 0 then null else b end as ratio
from mytable;
```

This is standard SQL and works in Oracle as well as in about every other RDBMS. Oracle also provides the function `NULLIF` as a shorter way to write the expression in the second query.

Comment: here I am getting 00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: It works for me. Demo: http://rextester.com/WBLH32768, You probably made a mistake when copying my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`nullif`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions102.htm) to return `null` instead of raising an error:

```
select  A / nullif(B, 0) as division
from    YourTable
```

If your numbers are stored as `varchar`, cast them to numbers before using them:

```
select  to_number(A) / nullif(to_number(B), 0) as division
from    YourTable
```

Comment: But then i am getting 00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Comment: What's the data type of `A` and `B`? Could you post the table definition?

Comment: If they're stored as `varchar`, convert them to numbers using `to_number` before using them. Added an example to the answer.